# Using GKStateMachine with multiple ways to get to a state

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

**Background**

I've created an SpriteKit app that creates a leaderboard for a tournament. I'm trying to make the code a bit more robust by using `GKStateMachine` to remove some of the ugly code I have for handling states. I also just want to experiment with state machines so that I learn how to use this framework for a future project. For all of the examples I've seen (and there aren't many) they've had pretty simple state machine diagrams. Mine is slightly more complicated. I just want to make sure I'm using these APIs in their intended way.

QUESTION: In the examples I've seen, `- didEnterWithPreviousState:` never has any if statements in it, which means that I guess it's assumed that there is only one way to get to each state. Would you use if statements in `- didEnterWithPreviousState:` to make decisions on how to handle multiple ways a state may be entered?

**Project Info**

In the scene where I set up the leaderboard I'm selecting `contestant` icons and placing them into the leaderboard. If the amount of contestants is NOT a power of 2, then "byes" need to be selected first.

[image]

Once all of the "byes" locations have been selected the leaderboard dynamically creates the slots for the contestants who will have to face each other for round 1.

[image]

Once all of the round 1 contestants have been selected, then the will seek confirmation of the choices and then move from the setup scene to the leaderboard scene.

[image]

Here's what my current states look like (but this is without using `GKStateMachine`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` and `if` statements are common patterns in `GKState` classes. You can add as many cases as you need.

```
// Objective-C
- (BOOL)isValidNextState:(Class)stateClass {
    return stateClass == [NormalState class] || stateClass == [AbnormalState class];
}

- (void)didEnterWithPreviousState:(GKState *)previousState {
    if (previousState == [NormalState class]) {

    } else if (previousState == [AbnormalState class])  {

    }
}

// Swift
override func isValidNextState(stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
    switch stateClass {
    case is NormalState.Type:
        return true

    default:
        return false
    }
}

override func didEnterWithPreviousState(previousState: GKState?) {
    if let _ = previousState as? NormalState {

    }
}
```